# Axios and Express: Sending params in Get request sends an empty params object to the backend

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest, axios, sequelize.js

Here's the **Axios request**:

```
API.get("api/client/getClientByPK", { params: { id: 22 } });
```

Here's the **Express router**:

```
router.get("/getClientByPK", function(req, res) {
  logger.info("req.params", JSON.stringify(req.params));
  clientServices.getClientByPK(req.params.id, res);
});
```

> getClientByPk

```
var getClientByPK = function(clientPk, res) {
  models.client
    .findByPk(clientPk)
    .then(clientFound => {
      logger.debug("clientPk", clientPk);
      logger.info("clientFound", JSON.stringify(clientFound));
      if (clientFound != null) {
        res.status(200).json(clientFound);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "ClientNotFound" });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      logger.error(error);
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
};
```

This is the **log result**:

```
2020-03-16T15:31:10+0100 <info> client_routes.js:12  req.params + {}
2020-03-16T15:31:10+0100 <debug> ClientServices.js:21  clientPk + 
2020-03-16T15:31:10+0100 <info> ClientServices.js:22  clientFound + null
```

I have tested the Backend with **POSTMAN**, and it works perfectly. So I believe the problem lies in the **AXIOS request**.
**PS:** I've found only one answer on SO suggesting that I use data instead of params but it's still the same result.

Comment: I think 'params' object is treated as 'query' on serverside. Could you change 'req.params' to 'req.query' and let me know what you get

Answer (score 2):

Axios sends the `params` object as query parameters.

You should access the query parameters in express through `req.query` not `req.params`